# Is there an easier deployment method than hudson + ant?

Tags: php, deployment, ant, jenkins, continuous-integration

For the last several years I have used jenkins/hudson and ant for my deployments.

But overall I find it quite heavy handed.

Is there a free, more lightweight software (preferable online) I can use?

What I need to do is

1. Grab my php files from git (based on time, commit or manual)
2. Replace some values in a config file
3. Push/Sync to a remote server

So far I have found http://www.deployhq.com and http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/go-continuous-delivery

*Sorry if this is not the right overflow for this type of question.

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed lots of different deployment solutions available.

For the workflow you describe, it might be worth considering [BuildMaster](http://inedo.com/buildmaster). It's not hosted, but it's a pretty easy way to build (or in your case... test?) and deploy files. It would also manage your configuration files across different environments. For a simple example, check out how [The Daily WTF is deployed](http://inedo.com/specifics/the-daily-wtf) using BuildMaster.

(disclaimer: I work for Inedo)